Segmentation fault trying to drop caches
I have been using a script to regularly check for the cached memory and clear it out when there is not enough free memory available. To avoid being too aggressive with clearing the script first does echo "1" > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches and then checks again before going to 2 or 3.
This worked fine for some time, but lately the script fails to clear cached memory. Manually running the command closes my ssh session. Using sudo echo "1" > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches instead I get a Segmentation fault and memory is not cleared. Weirdly going up to 2 or 3 works just fine and clears memory.
Restarting the machine level 1 does work again. Since level 2 and 3 work the file isn't being locked for writing. It's only level 1 that behaves this way. I changed the script to only use level 2 now, but as this has now happened on multiple machines I do wonder what the cause might be. Machines all running different versions of Ubuntu from 20 to 24.
Segfault from kern log: https://pastebin.com/sa8yd3HS

Are there any other errors in dmesg immediately above the segfault? I/O errors in particular?

@grawity Not that I can find, just the seg faults. I can see it dropping caches fine and then 5 mins later starts seg faulting on that.

Do not call drop_caches in an attempt to improve performance. Linux automatically quickly reclaims from these when needed. Throwing them out is itself overhead, then forces more I/O and other work when the data is referenced again.
Personally, I would expect quantitative evidence of memory contention before approving performance mitigations like poking at drop_caches. Merely having a lot of cached kernel objects does not prove a performance issue.

Memory pressure stall information (/proc/pressure/memory) over time.
Profiling some kernel memory reclaim functions to measure their overhead.
Ideally measuring application performance to get an idea of user response time, and does this matter.

No, drop_caches should not crash when used. I am not enough of a kernel hacker to troubleshoot that general protection fault, not remotely. If you have support plans with kernel expertise, either Canonical or third party, open a support case and ask them.

It's not in an attempt to improve performance. It's to retain at least some free memory for rapid allocation should it be needed, because cached or buffered memory being cleared for that has caused issues with some applications in the past. Only triggered below 10% free memory.

What specific problem with memory reclaim did you observe, and on what kernel version?  What was the contents of /proc/pressure/memory   at the time of high memory pressure?  You are making a claim an automatic function of the kernel is not adequate for your needs without providing quantitative evidence of the problem.  My Linux hosts can approach 10% MemFree and perform fine because there is plenty of  MemAvailable to reclaim.

It was an application running in mono that attempted to allocate memory and crashed with an out of memory exception because most of the memory was either cached or buffered. Did not check what the kernel was doing at the time. Also not the point of the question either.
